# Cross domain get request with jQuery using jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm having trouble getting a cross domain request to work with jQuery and can't seem to figure out what's going on. Basically I'm trying to query a Solr server and neither the success or error functions are being called. When in the Javascript console for Chrome I do not get any sort of error. Also, when I only type in "mysolrserver/?wt=json&q=title:uw" into the url bar I get a json formatted string.

I replaced my ip with "mysolrserver".
Thank you in advance!

My javascript file:

```
"use strict";
(function() {
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("search").onclick = request;
    }

    function request(){
        $.ajax('mysolrserver/?wt=json&q=title:uw', {
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(data){
            alert("Success");
          },
          error: function(error, data, type){
            alert(data + ": " + type + "."); //type isn't giving any response.
          }
        });
    }
})();
```

**Update:**
In the json response I get from the server, the beginning section is this (I ommited the 'response' section because it's return a ton of text):
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":2,"params":{"q":"title:uw","callback":"jQ‌​uery1102035263595171272755_1383771206800","_":"1383771206801","wt":"json"}},"resp‌​onse":'

So I assume you're meaning this: 
"callback":"jQuery1102035263595171272755_1383771206800"

Comment: the jsonp response format must be `jsonpcallback({})` where `jsonpcallback` is the name of the callback function passed from the client

Comment: what is the jsonpcallback parameter name expected by the server

Comment: can you post the full json response please.

Comment: it is not a jsonp response...

Comment: How so? How to I make a jsonp response? Do you mean like Dan mentioned in his answer below?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is sending a function name in a parameter called `callback` that it needs your JSON service to call when it returns. Solr needs this parameter to be called `json.wrf` according to [the Solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON). Try adding [a `jsonp:` option to your jQuery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like this:

```
    $.ajax('mysolrserver/?wt=json&q=title:uw', {
      jsonp: 'json.wrf',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data){
        alert("Success");
      },
      error: function(error, data, type){
        alert(data + ": " + type + "."); //type isn't giving any response.
      }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using this as my TA recommended it but it didn't make any difference. Just tried it again to be sure and still had no luck.

Comment: If you do it by hand (go to `mysolrserver/?wt=json&json.wrf=callme&title:uw` in your browser) does solr correctly wrap the object it sends in a function call? If not, you'll need the help of [people who've worked more with solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solr)

Comment: Yes it does (0 documents is expected because I didn't use a query):

callme({"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"json.wrf":"callme","wt":"json"}},"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]}})